# WordPress Posts/Page Content Blank on Backend After Site Move

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

After moving a WordPress website from one server to another I have encountered an odd issue. Everything works great, until I go edit any post or page and I am presented with an empty content box on the backend. (see image).

[image: The empty content box.]

All of the posts and pages are displayed properly on the front end except that there are strange characters in the content (see image).

[image: Strange characters]

If I try to republish a post, then the empty content saves over the hidden content and the post becomes empty on the front end.

I disabled all plugins and switched themes which changed nothing.

Did I corrupt my database on transfer or is there some other reason that might have caused this?

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` were both set to `''` (empty string) in `wp-config.php`. I updated them to the following values and all issues were resolved:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
```